# C# - No module handle?

Tags: c#, hook

I am trying to make a program that will be able to detect keyloggers on my system by installing a global hook on WH_DEBUG. My problem is, that GetModuleHandle (and - it seems - all of the other, more obscure ways of getting the module handle) return with null. I was hoping that someone here would be able to shed some light on the situation.

MainForm.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace MouseTimer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static void log(String ltxt)
        {
            ((MainForm)Application.OpenForms[0]).richTextBox1.Text += ltxt+"\n";
            ((MainForm)Application.OpenForms[0]).richTextBox1.SelectionStart = ((MainForm)Application.OpenForms[0]).richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            ((MainForm)Application.OpenForms[0]).richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        }
        public int DbgEvt(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            log("DBGEVT: "+wParam.ToString());
            return 0;
        }

        void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowsHook wh = new WindowsHook(HookType.WH_DEBUG, DbgEvt);
            wh.Install();

        }
    }
}
```

WindowsHook.cs:

```
public class WindowsHook
{
    public delegate int HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    protected IntPtr m_hhook = IntPtr.Zero;
    protected HookProc m_filterFunc = null;
    protected HookType m_hookType;
    public delegate void HookEventHandler(object sender, HookEventArgs e);
    public event HookEventHandler HookInvoked;
    protected void OnHookInvoked(HookEventArgs e)
    {
        if (HookInvoked != null)
            HookInvoked(this, e);
    }
    public WindowsHook(HookType hook)
    {
        m_hookType = hook;
        m_filterFunc = new HookProc(this.CoreHookProc); 
    }
    public WindowsHook(HookType hook, HookProc func)
    {
        m_hookType = hook;
        m_filterFunc = func; 
    }       
    protected int CoreHookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (code < 0)
            return CallNextHookEx(m_hhook, code, wParam, lParam);

        HookEventArgs e = new HookEventArgs();
        e.HookCode = code;
        e.wParam = wParam;
        e.lParam = lParam;
        OnHookInvoked(e);
        return CallNextHookEx(m_hhook, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    public void Install()
    {

        using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
                using (ProcessModule m = p.MainModule)
        {
                m_hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(m_hookType, m_filterFunc,
               GetModuleHandle(m.ModuleName), 0);
        }

    }

    public void Uninstall()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hhook); 
        m_hhook = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public bool IsInstalled
    {
        get{ return m_hhook != IntPtr.Zero; }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        protected static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookType code, 
            HookProc func,
            IntPtr hInstance,
            int threadID);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        protected static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhook); 

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        protected static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhook, 
            int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

}
```

The thing is, when I try a (low-level) mouse hook, it hooks just fine without the module handle. So I'm not sure what the problem is. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: With the working mouse hook are you talking about a normal or a "lowlevel" mouse hook? Lowlevel hooks are completely different, and AFAIK they don't trigger debug hooks either. I recommend only writing lowlevel hooks in C#. For normal hooks use an unmanaged language like c.

Comment: I'm talking about a "lowlevel", why, what's the difference?

Comment: lowlevel hooks don't need a module handle. They're running in the original process. Global non "lowlevel" hooks get your dll injected into every process in which the hook triggers, and they need the handle to determine which dll to inject. Which implies injecting the CLR into all those processes => bad idea

Comment: Ah, I can see how that would be bad. Probably a huge performance drop as well. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global hooks are not supported for .Net.

See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804?wa=wsignin1.0

From which I quote:

> Except for the WH_KEYBOARD_LL low-level hook and the WH_MOUSE_LL
>   low-level hook, you cannot implement global hooks in the Microsoft
>   .NET Framework. To install a global hook, a hook must have a native
>   DLL export to inject itself in another process that requires a valid,
>   consistent function to call into. This behavior requires a DLL export.
>   The .NET Framework does not support DLL exports. Managed code has no
>   concept of a consistent value for a function pointer because these
>   function pointers are proxies that are built dynamically.

Comment: One could use an unmanaged wrapper, but even then it's still a bad idea.

Comment: Oh, I see, alright, thanks for that. Although I cannot fathom why, in my several hours of Googling for an answer to this, I didn't find that already. But thank you. This makes sense.